# Does qmake generate header dependencies using the equivalent of makedepends

Tags: qmake

I notice CMake and Automake automatically generate dependency files from the users source code. Does qmake have the same feature?

Answer (score 0):

Makefiles generated by qmake include dependencies between source files and header files. So if a header is changed all affected source files will be recompiled. But you have to enumerate header files correctly.